# Retrieve Last mysql rowd ID using ajax / jquery

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i know how to post data using javascript but im trying to work out how i can retrieve the last inserted row in a mysql table.

So i can use it in my success result.

Below is what i have so far but all it does is create the entry , i really want to direct the user to a page where they can now edit their new entry without having them click a button to go there first.

The code below has not got the part i really need, i just put it up so you can see my structure of what i am doing.

```
$("#CREATEDOCUMENT").click(function() {

var txt = $.ajax({
url: 'create_doc_entry.php',
async: true, 
type:'POST',
data:({
usr_id:$('input#usr_id').val(),
}) 

}).success;

$('.pleasewait').fadeIn('slow');    

setTimeout(function(){window.location="index.php?v=editdoc&id="+id;}, 2000);

});
```

As you can see from the above in the window.location url i have +id

I would really love that +id to be my last inserted id which i grab from the create_doc_entry.php file if you know what i mean.

Thanks in advance
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to modify `create_doc_entry.php` so that it prints the last inserted ID after the INSERT.

Then you probably should add the `success` setting in your ajax request, like this:

```
var txt = $.ajax({
    url: 'create_doc_entry.php',
    async: true, 
    type:'POST',
    data:({
        usr_id:$('input#usr_id').val(),
    }),
    success: function( data ) { alert(data); }
});
```

So you can parse or do whatever you want with `data` in the `success` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have tried what you said but im not sure i still understand the process. What i get now is an alert box but it shows no data. I do have the $id = mysql_insert_id() ; in the php file. How do i actually retrive the id i need? please

Comment: @jonnypixel In your php file you should `print $id;`. Then the alert box will display that ID. So you can use that ID in your redirect.

Comment: I love you man. In a very friendly sort of way. Thanks bro. Hey are you interested in paid work?

Comment: @jonnypixel haha, I have a job doing this sort of thing already :)

Comment: good work, i was just wondering cause i know in the US there are a lot of people out of work. Thanks again man :)